# Solr 5.0 and Nutch 1.10

Tags: solr, nutch

I am using Solr 5.0, Nutch 1.10 with cygwin on windows server 2008 R2. I am issuing the command as:

bin/crawl -D urls/ bin/urls crawl/ 2

As of my knowledge 2 is the number of rounds for crawling. When I execute this command and read the crawldb I receive only 127 url's which is very less as compared to what is expected. Also it does not crawl at deeper depth. When I issue this command for passing data to Solr:

bin/nutch solrindex http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/thetest crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*

and then perform search then I get only 20 url's in all. Can anyone help. I need to do a deeper depth crawling.

Answer (score 0):

You may increase number of round incremently which will fetch you more urls. You may see number of urls fetch in each round in **hadoop.log** file present in **./logs** folder.

You may refer this [link](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial)

Usage: crawl [-i|--index] [-D "key=value"]   
        -i|--index      Indexes crawl results into a configured indexer
        -D              A Java property to pass to Nutch calls
        Seed Dir        Directory in which to look for a seeds file
        Crawl Dir       Directory where the crawl/link/segments dirs are saved
        Num Rounds      The number of rounds to run this crawl for
     Example: bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/ urls/ TestCrawl/  2

```
 bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=$solrUrl cores/$coreName/urls cores/$coreName/crawl 2
```